# Making javascript counter stop

Tags: javascript, counter

I have this counter:

http://codepen.io/leticiamartinch/pen/YpJgqx

Here is the code:

```
var MAX_COUNTER = 1000000;
var counter = null;
var counter_interval = null;
var deadline = localStorage.deadline;

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function resetCounter() {
    counter = MAX_COUNTER;
}

function stopCounter() {
    window.clearInterval(counter_interval);
    deleteCookie('counter');
}

function updateCounter() {
    var msg = '';
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter -= 1;
        msg = counter;
        setCookie('counter', counter, 1);
    }
    else {
        msg = "Counting finished.";
        stopCounter();
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = msg;
    }
}

function startCounter() {
    stopCounter();
    counter_interval = window.setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
}

function init() {
    counter = getCookie('counter');
    if (!counter) {
        resetCounter();
    }
    startCounter();
}

init();
```

I'd like it to decrease in a slower basis so that it doesn't seems to be a timer countdown but full number counter.

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish in the end? function startCounter() {
    stopCounter();
    counter_interval = window.setInterval(updateCounter, 5000);
} If you change the time interval here it will update you countdown each 5 seconds instead of one, if that is what are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess that you want it to look like e.g. a download counter which has real underlying data instead of a timed counter where people can see that it is just an artificial countdown.

I'd suggest to generate two random numbers - one for the next time interval till decrease and one for the amount of decrease. Set the time interval to be random between - let's say 1 and 3 and the amount between 1 and 5 (depending on how fast you want the countdown to be). You probably want to experiment with the values. Also don't set an initial value of 1000000 because that looks rather obviously fake.

Such an implementation could make sense for example when creating a mockup for a customer where you later put the real underlying data, such that your customer gets a feeling on how the counter will behave later.

If I'm guessing wrongly on what you initially want - please let us know and provide more information.

Here is what you'll get:

```
var MAX_COUNTER = 1294652;

var counter = null;
var counter_interval = null;
var deadline = localStorage.deadline;

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function resetCounter() {
    counter = MAX_COUNTER;
}

function stopCounter() {
    window.clearInterval(counter_interval);
    deleteCookie('counter');
}

function updateCounter() {
    var msg = '';
    if (counter > 0) {
        newDecreaseAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        counter -= newDecreaseAmount;
        msg = counter;
        setCookie('counter', counter, 1);

        // set new interval
        newInterval = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1) * 1000;
        counter_interval = window.setTimeout(updateCounter, newInterval);
    }
    else {
        msg = "Counting finished.";
        stopCounter();
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = msg;
    }
}

function startCounter() {
    stopCounter();
    updateCounter();
}

function init() {
    counter = getCookie('counter');
    if (!counter) {
        resetCounter();
    }
    startCounter();
}

init();
```